# Selenium issues in navigation tree

Tags: java, selenium

I am currently facing some problem with the expanding of the navigation tree. During playback, the selenium driver will click on the parent tree node but is unable to expand the tree map and locate the child node. Eclipse will then throw an exception -

> org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Element is not displayed (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information).

Have tried to use the wait (`WebElement element = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("itemTextLink5")));`) but it doesn't seem to be able to locate the particular element. Hence, it will throw a timeout exception -

> org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Timed out after 10 seconds waiting for element to be clickable:

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Apply")).click();   --> parent node     
driver.findElement(By.id("itemTextLink5")).click();    --> child node
```

I'm currently using JDK1.6, Selenium 2.46, IE 11. Not able to upgrade by JDK and Selenium version due to some restrictions to the project I'm working on.

Answer (score 0):

As you said your are able to click on parent element but not expanding means may be click is not simulated correctly. did you tried by

```
1.Try click on parent node with other different locators as linktext does not works here
2.providing the required wait to load page properly before click on parent node
3.if wait command does not work, use Thread.sleep which works for me in some cases
4. still click does not simulate properly then use javascript executor.
```

example:

```
 WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("your element"));
 JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
 executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

Off-course on clicking parent node tree is not expanded so we receive error for child node as it is not displayed. Try above suggestions.

Thank You,
Murali